# C# WPF binding to observable object in singleton class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, singleton

I try to bind a singleton to my listview.
The singleton is a simple logging class who put all new incoming logging messages in an observable object. This object is bound to my xaml code.

The singleton class:

```
namespace Log
{
public sealed class CLog
{
    private CLog() { }

    private static object m_lock = new object();

    private static CLog _instance;
    public static CLog instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (m_lock)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new CLog();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<CLogMessage> _logs = new ObservableCollection<CLogMessage>();
    public ObservableCollection<CLogMessage> logs
    {
        get
        {
            if (_logs == null)
            {
                _logs = new ObservableCollection<CLogMessage>();
            }
            return _logs;
        }
    }

    public void AddString(string source, string message)
    {
        CLogMessage log = new CLogMessage();
        log.time = DateTime.Now;
        log.source = source;
        log.message = message;
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            (Action)delegate()
        {
            logs.Add(log);
        });
    }
}

public sealed class CLogMessage
{
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

}

My binding in a ListView:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:CLog.instance}, Path=logs}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Zeit" Width="140" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding time}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Quelle" Width="140" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding source}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Nachricht" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding message}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that my view is not updated. I tested the singleton class for debugging purposes randomly via a simple CLog.instance.logs.Count() from different classes. Works absolutly fine, i just have problems with displaying the items in my view.
My very vague suggest is that i have to implement a notification for the bound object itself?

Thank you

Comment: Two random notes, Properties in C# should be PascalCase, and that technically isn't a singleton, since you don't have a private constructor. Beyond that, I'm not entirely sure why you are having issues, though that x:Static sure looks suspicious... Any reason why you can't expose that collection via a property on your VM?

Comment: I use x:Static because the property "instance" is static.

Comment: I've had issues issues in the past with the UI not updating if I add an item to a collection using the Dispatcher. Does it work if you remove the dispatcher code?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Because the author using a singleton pattern for `CLog`.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Well, he *tried* to use one, though I bet I can make two of them ;).

Comment: @Rachel Hi, i get thread errors if i don't use them.

Comment: @user2015618 I would suggest implement a locking object to ensure only a single instance gets created. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10242789/302677) for an example.

Comment: @Rachel Thank you for the link, i already know it but it's still not working. When i'm not using the delegate i get: This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread. I also updated my source.

Comment: Well, i better go to sleep. I found the error. The log view is bound as a usercontrol to my panel. So i just put a new gridview to my panel, also using the exact bindings like my logging control do and voila, it worked. After that i found a, well, very stupid setting in my logging usercontrol settings: "height='34'". So the data was always displayed but the box was just too small. Yes, i'm very ashamed. Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: @user2015618 lol I've done many stupid mistakes like that, especially when I miss out on my sleep. Glad you got it sorted out though

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is caused by the listview being bound to a null item source from the beginning. As I don't have a machine to test this now, perhaps you can verify if that's true, by changing the code around `_logs` :

```
private ObservableCollection<CLogMessage> _logs = 
    new ObservableCollection<CLogMessage>();
public ObservableCollection<CLogMessage> logs
{
    get { return _logs; }
}

public void AddString(string source, string message)
{
    CLogMessage log = new CLogMessage();
    log.time = DateTime.Now;
    log.source = source;
    log.message = message;
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
        (Action)delegate()
    {
        _logs.Add(log);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry. That solution did not do the trick. But isn't that the task of the property? It checks if a object is null or not and will create a new instance if so. Well, it's not working anyway.